# iOS AudioPlayer memory leak in Simple Soundboard App

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on a simple soundboard app where whenever you push a button it plays a corresponding sound. However, I don't appear to be releasing my variables correctly (or at all really right now since I reverted my code back to where it WORKS playing the sounds but has memory leaks) and I know it won't meet app store standards. I need to figure out how to fix this problem so any help is appreciated!

My ViewController.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
 {

}

-(IBAction)pushTropical;
-(IBAction)pushVakidis;
-(IBAction)pushTwiggy;
-(IBAction)pushScootsy;
-(IBAction)pushJackiePass;
-(IBAction)pushJackieIntro;
-(IBAction)pushBB;
-(IBAction)yourProblem;
-(IBAction)pushSuckMy;
-(IBAction)pushBallGirl;
-(IBAction)pushGoofballs;
-(IBAction)pushHavingFun;
-(IBAction)pushwhoBambi;
-(IBAction)pushExcited;
-(IBAction)pushdirtyHippie;
-(IBAction)pushBambiMother;
-(IBAction)pushEverybodyPanic;
-(IBAction)pushSmallChild;
-(IBAction)pushBurnHouse;
-(IBAction)pushTitanic;
-(IBAction)pusherection;

@end
```

My ViewController.m is:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"



@implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction)pushTropical {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Tropical" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];





}

-(IBAction)pushVakidis {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Vakidis" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}
-(IBAction)pushBB {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"BB" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushTwiggy {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Twiggy" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushScootsy {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Scootsy" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushJackiePass {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"JackiePass" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushJackieIntro {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"JackieIntro" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushyourProblem {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"yourProblemShort" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushBallGirl {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"ballgirl" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushGoofballs {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"goofballs" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushSuckMy {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"yourfamily" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushHavingFun {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"dukesBase" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushwhoBambi {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"whoBambi" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushExcited {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"dukesIsExcited" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushdirtyHippie {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"dirtyhippie" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushBambiMother {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"BambiMother" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushEverybodyPanic {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"EverybodyPanic" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushSmallChild {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"SmallChild" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushBurnHouse {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"BurnHouse" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pushTitanic {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"Titanic" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

-(IBAction)pusherection {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"erection" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];


}

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

I've tried releasing 'theAudio' variable within the various push methods (pushTropical, pushBurnHouse, etc.) like so...

```
-(IBAction)pushExcited {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"dukesIsExcited" ofType:@"m4a"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

    [theAudio release];





}
```

...however then the sound refuses to play at all. So I'm at a loss, because whenever I try to release 'theAudio' anywhere but inside of those functions it won't recognize it to release it. Help!

Answer (score 3):

You should release the AVAudioPlayer via the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate) method after you've set your class as the delegate.

i.e.:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [player release];
}
```

Once you've done this, all should be well.